# return latitude and longitude to access to another method

Tags: android, google-maps

I have code to get my location on google map.
I want to return latitude and longitude value to access in another method. How can I do that?

```
private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geDeviceLocation: mendapatkan lokasi pengguna");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted){
                Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: lokasi ditemukan");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                            if (currentLocation != null){
                                moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                        DEFAULT_ZOOM);
                            }

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: lokasi tidak ditemukan");
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Lokasi tidak ditemukan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geDeviceLocation: SecurityException"+e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't return a value from a callback, you can declare a class variable `public double mLatitude`, and same for latitude and then assign them in your `onComplete`

Comment: it still not working. It gives me `0,0` values when I try to use the `mLatitude` and `mLongitude` to another method

Comment: It may be possible that by the time you are trying to use latitude and longitude they are not yet obtained.

Comment: it works now. It not working if I put `mLatitude` to `onMapReady()`.